# What do _2_1_ and CONCAT11 mean in Ghidra?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, ghidra

I've been messing around with a program in Ghidra, and I came across these four lines of code. I found something about CONCAT11 meaning a concatenation between two one-byte operands, but I don't understand what part of the input `user_input._2_1_` and `(undefined)user_input` represent.

The code in C:

```
  read(0,&user_input,5);
  uVar1 = user_input;
  uVar2 = user_input._1_1_;
  local_16._0_2_ = CONCAT11(user_input._2_1_,(undefined)user_input);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`CONCAT11(x, y)`**

Performs `( ((uint16_t)x) << 8 ) | (uint8_t)y` on bytes `x` and `y`.

---

**`user_input._2_1_`**

`user_input` is a variable. That fact that you can use the `.` operator on it makes it a some kind of structure. `_2_1_` would be one of its fields. Obviously, it's a generated name. I presume the two numbers are an offset and a size. So it would be a one byte field found at the third byte of the structure.

---

**`(undefined)user_input`**

I don't think this is valid code.

We know that `CONCAT11` will be provided a byte. So `(undefined)user_input` must refer to an operation that reads a byte. This byte must surely be the first byte of `user_input`. So that would make it a reference to `user_input._0_1_`.

Well, it could be the first byte of a multi-byte field (`*(char*)&user_input._0_?_`), but that seems unlikely.

I think `(undefined)` is used because of the lack of information needed to resolve this ambiguity.

---

This is all guesswork.